# MVC and Crud Coldfusion 10

Tags: model-view-controller, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am a big fan of ColdFusion just haven't used it for awhile. When I used to build sites, I would use the Illudium PU-36 Code Generator to create my MVC coding based on MYSQL. It worked great, but as I am getting back into ColdFusion it is not working with CF10. Being out of the ColdFusion world for a while, I am not sure how things are being done.

I liked the way the PU-36 generator would layout the basic structure(MVC) from the database and I could go from there - even though every change would take a little work. I still understood the starting structure and how to make the changes from there. It provided a good start.

Is the hibernate part of ColdFusion what I should be looking at.

I liked the the MVC basics based on a generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PU-36 thing only deals with the data-abstraction layer as far as I can tell, and not really anything to do with MVC. The Hibernate wrapper in CF10 would replace all that for you these days.

As far as the MVC side of things go, there's a bunch of frameworks out there, and which is the most appropriate for you is a subjective thing, so you probably need to do your own investigations there. I've messed around with [Coldbox](http://www.coldbox.org/) a bit, but find it a bit heavy for my liking (it just does too much). However other people swear by it. I have had a superficial look at [Framework One](http://fw1.riaforge.org/), which is much lighter and more how I'd want a framework to be (mostly out of the way). And there are a bunch of others, which Google will help you investigate.

Comment: When I was using the PU-36 it had a scaffolding template for Coldbox to create the MVC from the database that would work within the Coldbox framework. It was just the way I was doing things and it worked well. I am familiar with Sean Corfield's FW/1. It sounds like I need to look more towards CF10 hibernate and incorporate it into my framework of choice. Thanks Adam.

Comment: Ah OK. I was running from memory from the last time I looked at it quite a number of years ago, plus a refresher from http://cfcgenerator.riaforge.org/ where it seemed to be claiming to only do DB proxies. I stand corrected. I don't see how one can get from a data model to MVC, but I guess it's just for adding a UI for CRUD operations, rather than the MVC for an actual application (which I don't see how can be inferred from the data model)? The CF10 Hibernate stuff is fairly straight forward to use, so is def worth looking at.